# rails looks for en when hb was defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my code:

```
I18n.default_locale = "hb"
```

But when I run my app (both in development or in production) I get an error rendered in the page itself, like:

```
Is personal event translation missing: en, activerecord, errors, models, event,
attributes, is_personal_event, e_event_category_mandatory
```

Why doesn't rail listen to the default language?

(I have e_event_category_mandatory in locales)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem was not in rails but with the server.

I used the "thin" server and that caused the problem.

When I used the regular webrick, all was OK.